# Teclado de EditText modifica Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, xml

Buenas a todos!
Estoy trabajando en un juego para Android, el cual cuenta con un `EditText` de tipo numérico. Al tocar en él, se despliega el teclado, y al hacerlo modifica el tamaño de mi *layout* padre, que es un `RelativeLayout`.
El problema es que éste tiene asignada a la propiedad `android:background` una imagen *.png* y ésta se escala al tamaño del `RelativeLayout` y no queda bien.
¿Hay alguna forma de que esto no suceda?

Agrego el *.xml* a modo de guía, aunque es un poco largo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/juego"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context="derivadadx.juegodelnumero.Juego"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="@string/numInput"
        android:textColorHint="@color/negro"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/borde_rojo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/verificar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/numInput"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/separacion_elementos"
        android:text="@string/verificar"
        android:background="@drawable/boton_negro"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/columnas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/verificar"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/separacion_elementos"
        android:background="@drawable/borde_verde">

        <TextView
            style="@style/AreaDeResultados"
            android:text="@string/columna_numero"/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/AreaDeResultados"
            android:text="@string/columna_aciertos"/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/AreaDeResultados"
            android:text="@string/columna_regular"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/columnas"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borde_azul">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numeros"
                style="@style/AreaDeResultados"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aciertos"
                style="@style/AreaDeResultados"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/regulares"
                style="@style/AreaDeResultados"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Lo que hace que se muestre esto:

[image: App sin tocar]

Y al tocar en el campo del `EditText`, esto es lo que sucede:

[image: Ingresando un número]

Ahí se puede ver cómo modifica el `ScrollView` y demás elementos dentro del `RelativeLayout`, lo cual no es el problema, sino que modifica la imagen de `background` del mismo.

Comment: No podemos ayudarte si nos muestras el codigo xml

Comment: Hola eso es algun programa para modelar o es el diseño de tu app?

Comment: Es el diseño, así lo fuí dejando yo. La hoja cuadriculada de atrás está hecha en paint jaja.